# Issue with gcloud compute reset-windows-password using service account in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, passwords, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am facing an issue while using the `gcloud compute reset-windows-password` command in Google Cloud. When I try to execute the following command with my main account, everything works as expected:

```
gcloud compute reset-windows-password my-instance --zone=my-zone --project=my-project
```

However, when I attempt to run the same command using a service account, I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.reset-windows-password) Did not receive password in a reasonable amount of time. Please try again.
If this persists, confirm that the clock on your local system is correct.
Current UTC time on your system: [2023-08-21 13:11:24.059083]
```

I've already verify both the connection and the system time and everything appears to be correct. At this point, I'm starting to suspect that the issue might be related to a lack of permissions associated with the service account. However, I'm unsure how to address this or troubleshoot further. Are there specific permissions or configurations required for a service account to successfully execute the `reset-windows-password` command?

**Update**

Below I report the configuration of the permissions of my service account for the project:

[image]

Comment: You have posted this question multiple times on multiple Stack forums. Post one time and delete the others. **Do not SPAM questions.** You will be downvoted for doing that. You have an answer. If that answer does not solve your problem, provide more information to identify a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I proceeded to add the username in the gcloud instruction like this:

```
gcloud compute reset-windows-password my-instance --zone=my-zone --project=my-project --user=my-user
```

This creates the user `myuser` on the Windows server (unless it already exists) and the password is successfully reset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have required roles and permissions to generate credentials for Windows Server VMs. The user running this command must have **write permission** for the Google Compute Engine project containing the Windows instance. The following are the IAM roles for which users using windows virtual machines need to have.

- Compute Instance Admin (v1) (role/compute.instanceAdmin.v1) on the VM or project.
- If your VM uses a service account: Service Account User (role/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the service account or project.

Since you have a service account for your instance, you need to have a **ServiceAccountUser** role for the serviceaccount. You can also be able to get the required permissions through [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) or other [predefined roles.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Refer to the [cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/generating-credentials#gcloud) for more information on generating credentials for Windows VM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question to show the permissions I've set for my service account. I tried adding the "Service Account User" role but nothing seems to have changed. I also tried restarting the server I have to manage but the error remained the same.